# can any one please explain in simple terms phase change of reflected light

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Phase change is used to explain interference in thin films . The concept is not explained there . Does the change in direction by 180 mean phase change ?

Answer (score 3):

For waves, reflection off of a fixed boundary causes an inverted reflected wave (a 180 deg phase shift), while reflection off of a free boundary causes no phase shift.  Excellent examples of this can be found at PhET.  See [this](http://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/wave-on-a-string/latest/wave-on-a-string_en.html).

When light travels from a medium with a low index of refraction to a high-index material, it sees a "fixed" boundary and reflects with a 180 deg phase shift.  When light travels from a medium with a high index of refraction to a low index material, it sees a "free" boundary, and reflects with no phase shift. In order for you to work problems in this area, you need to know the index of refraction for the materials that are involved.

One example area that uses this information: if you are determining the coating thickness for glass lenses, such that you are using destructive interference to minimize unwanted reflections (e.g., inside binoculars), you need to select a set of materials (indices of refraction) that guarantee that reflections from the top and bottom surfaces of the lens coating ensure a pair of reflected rays that are 180 deg out of phase for the given coating thickness.

Comment: The link is really a nice site.+1.